# ID Update Cassandra

Tags: playorm

I originally posted this elsewhere.

Synopsis:

Reading a log file with several bits of information. I'm using the time stamp (rounded down to minute) along with an id to build my key.  (1348495218081lID1). I do a look up prior to each put so see if a record with the same key exists in the DB. If I get a hit, I increment a counter field on the record returned, and do a put on that record. However, I don't see any records in the DB with a counter value greater than 1. I should have quite a number of these.

Here is an example:

```
            UserNameCountRecord countRecordLookup = new UserNameCountRecord();
            countRecordLookup.setStartDate(1348495218081l);
            countRecordLookup.setUserName(ID1);
            countRecordLookup.buildId();
            // getId() will return "1348495218081lID1"
            userNameCountRecord = findUserNameCountById(countRecordLookup.getId());
            if (userNameCountRecord != null) {
                userNameCountRecord.incrementCount();
                entityManager.put(userNameCountRecord, false);
            } else {
                userNameCountRecord = new UserNameCountRecord();
                userNameCountRecord.setStartDate(wibEntry.getStartDate());
                userNameCountRecord.setUserName(wibEntry.getUserName());
                userNameCountRecord.setCount(1);
                if (wibEntry.isKnownUserId()) {
                    userNameCountRecord.setKnownUserName(true);
                } else {
                    userNameCountRecord.setKnownUserName(false);
                }
                userNameCountRecord.buildId();
                entityManager.put(userNameCountRecord);
            }
            entityManager.flush();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for all the good work you have been doing!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. Sorry about this. My incrementor method was not working.

Answer (score 0):

uhm, If you are using playorm, you are using cassandra and this statement scares me a bit...

"I do a look up prior to each put so see if a record with the same key exists in the DB."

If you have two servers, then both may do a lookup and see the key does not exist AND then proceed to use the same key and have a conflict.  Typically you are better off generating TimeUUID or using playOrm UniqueKeyGenerator.generateKey (which playorm does for you on automatic id generation).  The ids from playorm are guaranteed to be unique within your cluster (as well as nice and short too compared to TimeUUIDs).

Anyways, you may want to rethink that as if your clsuter expands you could have issues though I don't know the rest of your design nor context.

Dean